# Morphological Gradients

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mathematical-morphology, cbir

I was trying to learn a few things on CBIR(content-based Information Retrieval). To do so I try to implement research papers and in one of the papers [[link](https://iarjset.com/upload/2015/june-15/IARJSET%2010.pdf)], the following is mentioned.

[image: Algo]

My main doubt is in step 3, I have done some digging on this and found 5 types of morphological gradients

- basic_gradient
- internal_gradient
- external_gradient
- horizontal_gradient
- vertical_gradient

**Are these the gradients the author is referring to or are there others that I am not considering?**

Comment: Who knows what the author is referring to? Is there no more detailed explanation? Write to the author and ask for the source code.

Comment: How would you proceed with shape extraction? Any method is fine.

Comment: You don't have enough information to reproduce the results. Usually, the two most basic morphological gradients are dilation-erosion and closing-opening. Contact the authors.